# visual studio item template - find out current folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4, visual-studio-templates

When you right click on a folder and '`add a new item`', is there a way to find out the current folder? I'm trying to display a default name for my custom item template in the add new item dialog box.

Want this to be dynamic based on the current folder.

I'm currently using the `DefaultName` property which gives me a static default name.

Comment: It's weird this information is not available anywhere. It's something quite common that people want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar and struggling to find out how to get the current folder the item is being added to